# Oscilloscope probe attenuation setting

Tags: oscilloscope, probe

I am trying to use a differential probe that has attenuation setting of 50X and 500X. However, my oscilloscope only has 1X, 10X, 100X, and 1000X. Would it cause any issue if there's a mismatch between attenuation of a probe and the oscilloscope, or would it merely result in the scope displaying a result scaled wrong?

Comment: Modern scopes often have custom scaling. Bring up the vertical menu that the channel in question and see if custom scaling is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope will just display a scaled waveform; there will be no other issues.

For example, if you plug in a 50x probe and set the scope to 100x, the values displayed on the scope are twice as large as the actual physical voltage. The scope just multiplies the measured voltage with the probe attenuation factor.